# Really simple Nginx rewrite to index.php needed, unable to find the solution

Tags: php, nginx, web, url-rewriting

I used the .htaccess to nginx rewrite converter and the solution is not working. In fact I'm unable to get any of my rewrites working no matter what I try. I am obviously doing something wrong here.

**I want to redirect all requests, except requests to PHP file, to index.php file and parse the request with PHP (no matter if the file/folder exists or not).**

Here's my minimalistic Nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # Make sure to set this as your actual server WWW root
        root html;
        # Index file
        index index.php;
        # Rewrite that directs everything to index file
        rewrite /!^(.*).php$ /./index.php last;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried things like "rewrite index.php" with no success. I also tried to put the rewrite in a separate location tag, but that made no difference either.

**I want to redirect all requests, except requests to PHP file, to index.php file and parse the request with PHP (no matter if the file/folder exists or not).**

What am I doing wrong other than just not having enough experience with Nginx?

Original .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^(.*)\.php$ ./index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you post your original `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Posted at the end of the question.

Comment: *"used the .htaccess to nginx rewrite converter and the solution is not working."* - That explains your problem. Instead of using a converter, have you tried to just formulate based on the nginx documentation what you want to achieve? That's much better than to whine about that some converter is not working.

Comment: I tried multiple options (as I explained in the question), but they do not stick. Even the most basic "rewrite index.php" does not work. And this line "rewrite /!^(.*).php$ /./index.php last;" is according to documentation. I even used Wordpress recommended nginx to see some of those examples, they just don't stick and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Besides, how difficult is it to just redirect everything except PHP to index.php file in the root? It should be a simple, short answer, but I cannot find it and Google has not helped either.